# Anchoring from options doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: jquery

This code works in Firefox but doesn't work in Chrome. Please help me out.
Clicking on option must send to corresponded DIV.

HTML:

```
<html>

<style>
div {
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

</style>
<body>

 <form >

    <select name="myselect" id="myselect">

    <option value="#year1">anchor-1</option>
    <option value="#year2">anchor-2</option>
    <option value="#year3">anchor-3</option>
    <option value="#year4">anchor-4</option>
    <option value="#year5">anchor-5</option>

    </select>

 </form>

  <div id = year1>YEAR 1</div>
  <div id = year2>YEAR 2</div>
  <div id = year3>YEAR 3</div>
  <div id = year4>YEAR 4</div>
  <div id = year5>YEAR 5</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function () {

        $("#myselect").on("click","option", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id  = $(this).attr('value');
        var   top = $(id).offset().top;
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: top - 120}, 500);
    });

    });
```

Try it out at jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/zutkh4o1/3/

Comment: try look at this https://jsfiddle.net/pq32h0u9/

Answer (score 0):

You might want the method "change", instead of clicking on an option itself:

```
$(function () {
    $("#myselect").change(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id  = $(this).val();
        var top = $(id).offset().top;

        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: top - 120}, 500);
    });
});
```

This divs id's needs double quotes:

```
<div id="year1">YEAR 1</div>
<div id="year2">YEAR 2</div>
<div id="year3">YEAR 3</div>
<div id="year4">YEAR 4</div>
<div id="year5">YEAR 5</div>
```

Lastly the value of each children of the select is normally like this:

```
 $(this).val();
```

And that's about it !

Comment: just a note, you dont need `$(this).children("option:selected").val()` you can just use `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the second parameter in the `.on()` - it's not dynamically loaded, so it's nothing special:

```js
$("#myselect").on("change", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).val();
  var top = $(id).offset().top;
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: top - 120 + "px"
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
div {
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select name="myselect" id="myselect">
    <option value="#year1">anchor-1</option>
    <option value="#year2">anchor-2</option>
    <option value="#year3">anchor-3</option>
    <option value="#year4">anchor-4</option>
    <option value="#year5">anchor-5</option>
  </select>
</form>
<div id=year1>YEAR 1</div>
<div id=year2>YEAR 2</div>
<div id=year3>YEAR 3</div>
<div id=year4>YEAR 4</div>
<div id=year5>YEAR 5</div>
```